# Lighthouse Graphql Subscriptions authentication returns 403 (subscriberByChannel() returns empty)

Tags: pusher, laravel-lighthouse

I'm trying to authenticate Subscriptions with Lighthouse ([docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/subscriptions/getting-started.html))

```js
const pusher = new Pusher('blabla', {
  cluster: 'eu',
  forceTLS: true,
  authEndpoint: 'https://app.test/graphql/subscriptions/auth',
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer blabla`
    }
  }
})
```

But when I run a subscription query, I get this

```
Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint.
Received status 403 from https://app.test/graphql/subscriptions/auth.
Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels.
See: https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users
```

So I decided to follow the flow.

And here is where it fails:

```php
//
// Nuwave\Lighthouse\Subscriptions > class Authorizer
//

public function authorize(Request $request): bool

  $subscriber = $this->storage->subscriberByRequest(
      $request->input(),
      $request->headers->all()
  );

  //  "$subscriber" is empty here. ==> return false

  if (! $subscriber) {
      return false;
  }

  ...
}
```

By stepping inside `$this->storage->subscriberByRequest()`, I get

```php
//
// Nuwave\Lighthouse\Subscriptions > class StorageManager
//

public function subscriberByRequest(array $input, array $headers): ?Subscriber
{
    $channel = Arr::get($input, 'channel_name');
    return $channel
        ? $this->subscriberByChannel($channel)
        : null;
}

public function subscriberByChannel(string $channel): ?Subscriber
{
    $key = self::SUBSCRIBER_KEY.".{$channel}";
    // At this point, "$key" equals "graphql.subscriber.private-lighthouse-blablabla"

    return $this->cache->get($key); //  This returns NULL
}
```

Can someone help?

Did I miss something?

My config:

```
# composer.json
"php": "^7.4",
"laravel/framework": "^7.0",
"nuwave/lighthouse": "^4.11",
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1"
```

```
# .env
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
LIGHTHOUSE_SUBSCRIPTION_STORAGE=file
LIGHTHOUSE_BROADCASTER=pusher
```

```
# config/lighthouse.php
'subscriptions' => [
    'storage' => env('LIGHTHOUSE_SUBSCRIPTION_STORAGE', 'file'),
    'broadcaster' => env('LIGHTHOUSE_BROADCASTER', 'pusher')
],
```

Comment: If the subscriber is missing might be that either the subscription was never created or your [client implementation](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.11/subscriptions/client-implementations.html) is not connecting to the correct channel. If you have webhooks wired up already it might also be that the subscriber was already cleaned up for some reason, you might want to disable webhooks while testing.

Comment: Having the same issue, client seems okay. Auth request is ok. Web hooks disabled.